# build int32_t from 4 uint8_t values

Tags: c

I have a function which constructs an `int32_t` from 4 `uint8_t` values and use the following test to have some confidence that my results are what they're expected to be because I'm depending on (what I believe is) Implementation Defined Behaviour.

Does it make sense what I'm doing?
Are there better ways to construct the int32_t?

```
int32_t expected = -1;
int32_t res = 0;
uint8_t b0 = 0xFF;
uint8_t b1 = 0xFF;
uint8_t b2 = 0xFF;
uint8_t b3 = 0xFF;                                                      
res |= b0;                                            
res |= b1 << 8;                                                   
res |= b2 << 16;
/* This is IDB, this value cannot be represented in int32_t */
res |= ((uint32_t) b3) << 24;                                                       
ck_assert(res == expected);
```

Comment: The entire idea of building an `int32_t` out of four `uint8_t`s is already implementation-defined. The results are different on a two's-complement system, a ones-complement system, and a sign-magnitude system. So the question is already implementation-defined. Not surprising that the answer is too. If you want the four `uint8_t`s to be treated as two's-complement, then you need to construct the `int32_t` in that manner (test the sign bit, etc.)

Comment: Are you asking how best to implement the function?  If so, what is its signature supposed to be?   Or are you asking how best to test the function?

Comment: Both really. The signature can be thought of as `int32_t fun(uint8_t data[4])`. two's-complement may be assumed. At the moment it's implemented like in the question. This code runs on x86-64 and Armv7-A architectures.

Comment: @RaymondChen The stdint.h types are _guaranteed_ to be 2's complement. So your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @Lundin I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef union
{
    uint32_t  u32;
    int32_t   i32;
    float     f;
    uint16_t  u16[2];
    int16_t   i16[2];
    uint8_t   u8[4];
    int8_t    i8[4];
    char      c[4];
} any32;
```

I keep that in my back pocket for all of my embedded system projects.  Aside from needing to understand the endian-ness of your system, you can build the 32bit values rather easily from 8bit pieces.  This is very useful if you are shuttling out bytes on a serial line or I2C or SPI.  It's also useful if you are working with 8.24 (or 16.16 or 24.8) fixed point math.  I generally supplement this with some #defines to help with any endian headaches:

```
//!\todo add 16-bit boundary endian-ness options
#if (__LITTLE_ENDIAN)
 #define FP_824_INTEGER  (3)
 #define FP_824_FRAC_HI  (2)
 #define FP_824_FRAC_MID (1)
 #define FP_824_FRAC_LOW (0)
#elif (__BIG_ENDIAN)
 #define FP_824_INTEGER  (0)
 #define FP_824_FRAC_HI  (1)
 #define FP_824_FRAC_MID (2)
 #define FP_824_FRAC_LOW (3)
#else
 #error undefined endian implementation
#endif
```

Comment: This is a bad ideas since they introduce reliance on endianess. This is worse than what the OP already got. Serialization of data is another, not necessarily related topic.

Comment: I wouldn't say it introduces endianness, your processor vendor did that!  The byte shifting certainly works for small ints to big ints, but if you have a float, double or other struct, this is a great way to tear it apart byte by byte..

Comment: That would be why I wrote _reliance_ on endianess. Writing endianess-dependent code when you could as well have written endianess-independent code is simply bad programming. _Particularly_ in embedded systems where you are more likely to encounter different endianess in different MCUs (and on top of that different _protocol_ endianess in communication protocols).

Comment: @Lundin I totally understand that point of view...  how would you move an IEEE-754 single precision float across an 8-bit serial line?  Protocol is 8-bit big endian, code has to run on 16-bit little endian, and 8-bit little endian.  I've always had to have a ".h" file somewhere that described the hardware and lets me trigger #if statements per architecture for the byte arrangements.  I'm all ears if there's a way around that.

Comment: Whenever dealing with more than one byte and there is an endianess issue, you use bit shifts. For example `u32 = (uint32_t)byte << 24` is guaranteed to write to the most significant byte of the u32, no matter endianess.That is, byte 0 for big endian or byte 3 for little endian. No need for compiler switches - the code is portable.

Comment: so for a float, you would have a (float) cast after the reassembly?  OK, but I'd be curious to see some execution speed comparisons on 8, 16 and 32 bit architectures...  the pre-compiler switches should be faster executing, especially on an 8- and 16-bit machines.

Comment: Bit shifts are usually among the fastest instructions, though the compiler is hopefully smart enough to replace them with byte copy instructions if those would be faster on a given CPU.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much the best way, except you should have a cast to `uint32_t` on every line, to avoid implicit conversions and signedness issues.

The main concern here is that performing bit-wise operations on signed operands tends to invoke poorly-defined behavior. In particular, look out for this:

- Left-shifting a bit into the sign bit of a signed number invokes undefined behavior. This includes shifting more bits than the type can hold.
- Left-shifting a signed variable which has a negative value invokes undefined behavior.
- Right-shifting a signed variable which has a negative value invokes implementation-defined behavior (you end up with either arithmetic or logical shift).

These concerns can all be avoided by making sure that you always shift using an unsigned type, like a `uint32_t`. For example:

```
res |= (int32_t) ((uint32_t)b1 << 8;)
```

The above code is rugged and good practice, since it doesn't contain any implicit promotions.

---

- Endianess is no concern in this case since you use bit shifts. Had you used any other method (type punning, pointer arithmetic etc) it would have been a concern.
- Signedness format is no concern in this case. The `stdint.h` types are guaranteed to use 2's complement. They will never use 1's complement or sign & magnitude.

Comment: Technically, it will still fall foul of C11 §6.3.1.3 paragraph 3 when you do the `res |= (int32_t) ((uint32_t)b1 << 24);` step. (Also there is a typo in the placement of the semicolon in your line of code.)

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes but that's not an issue. Implementation-defined there means "like 2's complement or other signedness formats". Which doesn't apply to `int32_t`, which is guaranteed to be in 2's complement. To my knowledge, there exist no 2's complement system in the real world which will do the conversion differently than a raw translation of the binary into 2's complement. There is absolutely no reason why "an implementation-defined signal" would be raised - that refers to systems with trap representations. At any rate, the alternative is code with explicit or latent UB.

Comment: That's why I prefixed my reply with "Technically,".

Answer (score 1):

If the implementation supports `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, and `uint8_t`, the following is guaranteed to have no implementation-defined values, or to raise an implementation-defined signal (see C11 §6.3.1.3):

```
#include <stdint.h>

void foo(void)
{
    uint8_t b0 = 0xef;
    uint8_t b1 = 0xbe;
    uint8_t b2 = 0xad;
    uint8_t b3 = 0xde;
    uint32_t ures = b0 | ((uint32_t)b1 << 8) |
                    ((uint32_t)b2 << 16) | ((uint32_t)b3 << 24);
    // Avoid implementation-defined value or signal...
    int32_t sres = (ures < (uint32_t)INT32_MIN) ?
                   (int32_t)ures : INT32_MIN + (int32_t)(ures & INT32_MAX);
}
```

The fixed-width signed integer types are guaranteed to have a 2's complement representation, but have no specific rules for converting out-of-range values (unlike the unsigned fixed-width integer types).

**EDIT**: Perhaps `(ures <= INT32_MAX)` would be more intuitive than `(ures < (uint32_t)INT32_MIN)` in the above code.

Comment: Implicitly there _are_ rules for how the conversion is done, namely a translation of the raw binary into 2's complement. This is how every system in the real world works. There is no need for strange checks against integer limits - simply rely on the fact that the code will run on real-world computers. A CPU does not know what makes the binary in a memory area signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, under real-world assumptions, the above mucking around to avoid IDB is unnecessary, but I wanted to give an answer that avoided IDB.